# (API-PLATFORM) How can I update one property of an entity at a time

Tags: api-platform.com

How can I update a property of an entity?

I would like to update (add / remove) the address property of an organization entity. It is a relation (ManyToMany) with the address entity. An organization can have one or more addresses; at one address, there can be multiple organizations.

Here is an excerpt from my organizational entity.

```
...
 * @ApiResource(
 *     iri="https://schema.org/Organization",
 *     routePrefix="/",
 *     shortName="Organisations",
 *     description="API Access to the Chafea Data Collector: Common : organisation Entity",
 *     collectionOperations={"GET", "POST"},
 *     itemOperations={"GET", "PUT", "PATCH"},
 *     attributes={
 *         "order"={
 *             "legalName",
 *             "acronym"
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
...
class Organisation extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"comment":"Primary Key, Auto generated"})
     */
    private $id;
...
    /**
     * @var address the address (not mandatory) of an organisation
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Address::class, inversedBy="organisations")
     *
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true).
     */
    private $address;
...
}
```

The JSON structure for the PUT operation (http://url-api/organisations/{id}).

```
{
  "legalName": "string",
  "acronym": "string",
  "address": [
    "string"
  ],
  "createdAt": "2020-10-29T13:01:20.637Z",
  "modifiedAt": "2020-10-29T13:01:20.637Z"
}
```

Do I have to retrieve the whole data set, update the IRIs of the address array and send back the updated data set (PUT)?

```
http.get(url);
...
data = {
  "legalName": "My organisation",
  "acronym": "MYORG",
  "address": [],
  "createdAt": "2020-10-29T13:01:20.637Z",
  "modifiedAt": "2020-10-29T13:01:20.637Z"
}
...
data.address": ['/addresses/1', '/addresses/5']
...
http.put(url,data,headers);
```

Maybe do I have to create a dedicated PUT operation for the address only?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is somewhere else, the ManyToMany relation is not working out of the box, it works one way (Address is creating the relation with Person, but Person creating the relation with Address)...